# React Js: Set input value from sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning `ReactJS` and trying to develop small `CRUD` form using it. At this point, I am trying to set `input values` from other `sibling component` to perform update. [image]

So, if I `click` on `edit button in first row` on grid, `Organzation Name` and `Description` input boxes should  get `"abc com"` and `"company Abc"` values respectively.

```
var OrganizationHandler = React.createClass(
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <OrganizationAPP onOrganizationSubmit=this.handleOrganizationSubmit} />
                <OrganizationList external_DeleteOrganization={this.DeleteOrganizationFromServer} data= {this.state.data}  />
            </div>
       );
    }
});

var OrganizationList = React.createClass({
    internal_DeleteOrganization: function(id) {
        this.props.external_DeleteOrganization(id);
    },
    render: function() {
        var results = this.props.data;
        var parsed_results = results.objects;
        var that = this;
        var organizations = parsed_results.map(function(organization){
            return <Organization onDeleteOrganization={that.internal_DeleteOrganization} id={organization.id} name={organization.name} description={organization.description} />
        });

        return(
            <div>
                {organizations}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Organization = React.createClass({
    handleDeleteClick: function() {
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.onDeleteOrganization(this.props.id);
    },
    handleEditClick: function () {
        alert(this.props.name);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="small-2 large-2 columns">{this.props.id}</div>
                <div className="small-4 large-4 columns">{this.props.name}</div>
                <div className="small-4 large-4 columns"> this.props.description}</div>
                <div className="small-2 large-2 columns">
                    <input type="button" onClick={this.handleDeleteClick} data-order={this.props.id} value="Delete" />
                    <input type="button" onClick={this.handleEditClick} data-order={this.props.id} value="Edit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var OrganizationAPP= React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {name: '',  description:''};
    },
    onChangename: function(e) {
        this.setState({name: e.target.value});
    },
    onChangedescription: function(e) {
        this.setState({description: e.target.value});
    },
    handleSubmit: function() {
        var name = this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value.trim();
        var description = this.refs.description.getDOMNode().value.trim();
        if (!description || !name) {
            return false;
        }

        this.props.onOrganizationSubmit('{"name":"' + name +'", "description": "' + description +'"}');
        this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value = '';
        this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value = '';
        this.setState({name: '', description: ''});
        return false;
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Organization Setup:</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="small-12 large-3 columns">
                            <label>Organization Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" ref="name" required value={this.props.name} onChange={this.onChangename}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="small-12 large-7 columns">
                            <label>description:</label>
                            <input type="text" required ref="description" value={this.props.description} onChange={this.onChangedescription}  />
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="small-2 large-3  columns">
                            <button type="submit"> Add </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

I have successfully performed `addition` and `deletion` operations but I don't know how can I set values to be edit in input boxes from sibling component. Please let me know if you don't understand anything as I just started learning `reactjs` and I know my code is not up to the mark.

Comment: To communicate between siblings, the data they depend on should be controlled by a common ancestor. Changes from one sibling will affect changes in the ancestor, which will pass the new data to the other sibling. Can you simplify your code example and/or fix the indentation? It would make it easier to offer advice.

Comment: @ssorallen Thank you for your response. I have edited the codes, would you please suggest me how to achieve this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example list editing app where editing an item content is done with a parent input (could easily be a sibling).

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

//React is for rendering our app UI. 
//Not for writing the app. 
//So the first step is building out your logic in whatever you prefer.
//That could be Backbone, some other framework, or plain JS as we do here.

//our app
var app = {

  //we'll tell this listener when we change
  listener: null,

  //a cheap way of creating IDs for our new data
  nextId: 3,

  //pre-populate our data
  rows: [
    {id: 1, name: "entry 1"},
    {id: 2, name: "entry 2"}
  ],

  //what data are we focused on
  focusedId: 1,

  //add a new row of data and set it to focused
  addRow: function () {
    var id = this.nextId++;
    this.rows.push({id: id, name: ("entry " + id)});
    this.setFocusedId(id);
  },

  //get the name property given the data id
  getName: function(id){
    return _.findWhere(this.rows, {id: id}).name;
  },

  //update the name property of the currently focused data
  updateName: function (name) {
    var id = this.focusedId;
    _.findWhere(this.rows, {id: id}).name = name;
    this.listener.changed();
  },

  //set the focused data
  setFocusedId: function (id) {
    this.focusedId = id;
    this.listener.changed();
  },
};

//a row component 
var Row = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    if (this.props.focused) {
      return <span>Value: {this.props.name} [editing]</span>;
    } else {
      return <span>
      Value: {this.props.name} 
        [<a href='#' onClick={this.props.focus}>edit</a>]
      </span>;
    }
  }
});

//the main view
var View = React.createClass({

  //our state is the app
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      app: app
    };
  },

  //before we render, start listening to the app for changes
  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.state.app.listener = this;
  },

  //update if the app tells us it changed
  changed: function () {
    this.forceUpdate();
  },

  //a handler we'll use for input fields
  textChanged: function (event) {
    this.state.app.updateName(event.target.value);
  },

  //let's render
  render: function () {
    var app = this.state.app;

    //build an array of row components
    var rows = _.map(app.rows, function (row) {
      var focus = function () {
        app.setFocusedId(row.id);
      };
      //the actual row component
      //give the row a unique id
      //give it a name, the focus handler function,
      //and tell it if it has the current focus
      return <li key={row.id}>
        <Row 
          name={row.name}
          focused={row.id == app.focusedId}
          focus={focus}
        />
      </li>;
    });
    //the main app view
    return <div>
    EDIT:
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={app.getName(app.focusedId)} 
        onChange={this.textChanged}
      />
      <ul>{rows}</ul>
      <a href="#" 
        onClick={function(){app.addRow()}}>
        add row
      </a>
    </div>;
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
    <View />
    , document.body);
```

**Here is a working example:**
http://jsbin.com/laxejufila/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer. would you please give example with some jsfiddle as I am sorry I couldn't get the idea clearly. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for being late in responding, I had issues with my development machine. I followed the steps you explained, its pretty much what I wanted. Thanks