# How to trigger a change in one component. From another component

Tags: reactjs

My react app has a component called ListOfTenants, which is basically a table with a radiobutton on each row. And eevery time a row is selected, I want that in the top bar navigation, there should be a component that says, You are working on tenant X.

So the ActiveTenant component is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import authAction from "../../redux/auth/actions";

class ActiveTenant extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        You aaare using tenant:
        {this.state.activetenant}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ActiveTenant;
```

The listtenants component is like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Table, Radio } from "antd";
import { adalApiFetch } from "../../adalConfig";

class ListTenants extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", {})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (!this.isCancelled) {
          const results = responseJson.map(row => ({
            key: row.ClientId,
            ClientId: row.ClientId,
            ClientSecret: row.ClientSecret,
            Id: row.Id,
            SiteCollectionTestUrl: row.SiteCollectionTestUrl,
            TenantDomainUrl: row.TenantDomainUrl
          }));
          this.setState({ data: results });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "Client Id",
        dataIndex: "ClientId",
        key: "ClientId"
      },
      {
        title: "Site Collection TestUrl",
        dataIndex: "SiteCollectionTestUrl",
        key: "SiteCollectionTestUrl"
      },
      {
        title: "Tenant DomainUrl",
        dataIndex: "TenantDomainUrl",
        key: "TenantDomainUrl"
      }
    ];

    // rowSelection object indicates the need for row selection
    const rowSelection = {
      onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
        console.log(selectedRows[0].key);
      },
      getCheckboxProps: record => ({
        type: Radio
      })
    };

    return (
      <Table
        rowSelection={rowSelection}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={this.state.data}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ListTenants;
```

And the App.js (main component)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Layout } from "antd";
import { Debounce } from "react-throttle";
import WindowResizeListener from "react-window-size-listener";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import authAction from "../../redux/auth/actions";
import appActions from "../../redux/app/actions";
import Sidebar from "../Sidebar/Sidebar";
import Topbar from "../Topbar/Topbar";
import AppRouter from "./AppRouter";
import { siteConfig } from "../../settings";
import themes from "../../settings/themes";
import { themeConfig } from "../../settings";
import AppHolder from "./commonStyle";
import "./global.css";

const { Content, Footer } = Layout;
const { logout } = authAction;
const { toggleAll } = appActions;
export class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { url } = this.props.match;
    const { height } = this.props;
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={themes[themeConfig.theme]}>
        <AppHolder>
          <Layout style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
            <Debounce time="1000" handler="onResize">
              <WindowResizeListener
                onResize={windowSize =>
                  this.props.toggleAll(
                    windowSize.windowWidth,
                    windowSize.windowHeight
                  )
                }
              />
            </Debounce>
            <Topbar url={url} />
            <Layout style={{ flexDirection: "row", overflowX: "hidden" }}>
              <Sidebar url={url} />
              <Layout
                className="isoContentMainLayout"
                style={{
                  height: height
                }}
              >
                <Content
                  className="isomorphicContent"
                  style={{
                    padding: "70px 0 0",
                    flexShrink: "0",
                    background: "#f1f3f6",
                    position: "relative"
                  }}
                >
                  <AppRouter url={url} />
                </Content>
                <Footer
                  style={{
                    background: "#ffffff",
                    textAlign: "center",
                    borderTop: "1px solid #ededed"
                  }}
                >
                  {siteConfig.footerText}
                </Footer>
              </Layout>
            </Layout>
          </Layout>
        </AppHolder>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    auth: state.Auth,
    height: state.App.toJS().height
  }),
  { logout, toggleAll }
)(App);
```

How can, on the OnChange event to trigger a change on the ActiveTenant component?

Update

Index (tenants)

One tab to register (form) and another tab is the list.

```
import React, { Component } from '../../../../../Library/Caches/typescript/2.9/node_modules/@types/react';
import { Row, Col, Tabs } from 'antd';
import PageHeader from '../../components/utility/pageHeader';
import Box from '../../components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../components/utility/layoutWrapper';
import ContentHolder from '../../components/utility/contentHolder';
import basicStyle from '../../settings/basicStyle';
import IntlMessages from '../../components/utility/intlMessages';
import RegisterTenantForm2 from './registertenantform2';
import ListTenants from './listtenants';

export default class extends Component {
  render(){
    const { rowStyle, colStyle, gutter } = basicStyle;
    const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;
    return (
      <div>
        <LayoutWrapper>
        <PageHeader>{<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}</PageHeader>
              <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
                <TabPane tab="Tenant Registration" key="1">
                          <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
                    <Col md={24} sm={24} xs={24} style={colStyle}>
                      <Box
                        title={<IntlMessages id="tabTitle.TenantRegistration" />}
                        subtitle={<IntlMessages id="pagesmalldescription.TenantRegistration" />}
                      >
                        <ContentHolder>
                            <RegisterTenantForm2 />
                        </ContentHolder>
                      </Box>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </TabPane>
                <TabPane tab="Tenant List" key="2">
                  <ListTenants/>
                </TabPane>
              </Tabs>



      </LayoutWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the approuter.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import asyncComponent from "../../helpers/AsyncFunc";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../dashboard"))
  },
  {
    path: "TenantAdministration",
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../RegisterTenant/index"))
  },
  {
    path: "SiteCollections",
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../SiteCollections/index"))
  },
  {
    path: "PageTemplates",
    component: asyncComponent(() => import("../PageTemplates/index"))
  }
];

class AppRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { url, style } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={style}>
        {routes.map(singleRoute => {
          const { path, exact, ...otherProps } = singleRoute;
          return (
            <Route
              exact={exact === false ? false : true}
              key={singleRoute.path}
              path={`${url}/${singleRoute.path}`}
              {...otherProps}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppRouter;
```

UPDATE 2
Topbar component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";import { Layout } from "antd";
import appActions from "../../redux/app/actions";
import TopbarUser from "./topbarUser";
import TopbarWrapper from "./topbar.style";
import themes from "../../settings/themes";
import { themeConfig } from "../../settings";
import ActiveTenant from "./activetenant";

const { Header } = Layout;
const { toggleCollapsed } = appActions;
const customizedTheme = themes[themeConfig.theme];

class Topbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { toggleCollapsed } = this.props;
    const collapsed = this.props.collapsed && !this.props.openDrawer;
    const styling = {
      background: customizedTheme.backgroundColor,
      position: "fixed",
      width: "100%",
      height: 70
    };
    return (
      <TopbarWrapper>
        <Header
          style={styling}
          className={
            collapsed ? "isomorphicTopbar collapsed" : "isomorphicTopbar"
          }
        >
          <div className="isoLeft">
            <button
              className={
                collapsed ? "triggerBtn menuCollapsed" : "triggerBtn menuOpen"
              }
              style={{ color: customizedTheme.textColor }}
              onClick={toggleCollapsed}
            />
          </div>

          <ul className="isoRight">
            <li>
              <ActiveTenant />
            </li>
            <li
              onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedItem: "user" })}
              className="isoUser"
            >
              <TopbarUser />
            </li>
          </ul>
        </Header>
      </TopbarWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    ...state.App.toJS()
  }),
  { toggleCollapsed }
)(Topbar);
```

Comment: I couldn't see the `ActiveTenant ` and `ListTenants ` reference in main component. Are you using Redux?

Comment: ActiveTenant is in the topbar, component

Comment: I just added more details, the topbarcomponent and also the container of the listenants component (its a template bought in envato) therefore I think I had to put all this code for the reader to be able to provide an answer. if I . am missing something let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm writing this basic example for your understanding. The activeTenant and click event is present in the Main component and passed as props to child component.

**Active Tenant**

```
class ActiveTenants extends React.Component{
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

    render(){

     return(
      <h1>{this.props.activetenant}</h1>
     )

    }

}
```

**ListTenants:**

```
class ListTenants extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
     super(props)
}

listTenant(tenants){
    return tenants.map(t=>{
        return (
         <li data-name={t.name} id={t.id}  onClick={(e)=>{this.props.tenatClick(e)}}>{t.name}</li>
        )
    });

}

render(){

 return(
    <ul>
        {this.listTenant([
            {name:"Tenant one",id:1},
            {name:"Tenant two",id:2},
            {name:"Tenant three",id:3}
        ])}

    </ul>
  )
 }
}
```

**Main Component:**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        activetenant :"Default tenant"
    }
  }

 changeTenant(e){
    let ele=e.target;
        this.setState({
          activetenant:ele.getAttribute('data-name')
        });
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>
            <ActiveTenants activetenant={this.state.activetenant} />
        </header>
                <div>
                        <ListTenants tenatClick={this.changeTenant.bind(this)} />               
                </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

While you clicking the list in the child component it will call the changeTenant function the main component because we bind the function with the main component. please find the working fiddle for the above example : [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/obp70zy9/)

**Note:**  You can do this very easier with Redux. But you need to spend some time to configure everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React 16, you could make use of the new [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

> In a typical React application, data is passed top-down (parent to
>   child) via props, but this can be cumbersome for certain types of
>   props (e.g. locale preference, UI theme) that are required by many
>   components within an application. Context provides a way to share
>   values like these between components without having to explicitly pass
>   a prop through every level of the tree.

Comment: you can have a look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884320/reactjs-how-to-update-a-component-from-another/24891646#24891646)

Comment: yes I am using react 16.2, and would like a detailed answer based on the code that I posted.

Comment: I'm just pointing you in one of the possible directions that you could take. I'm not going to code up a demo for you....

Comment: ok then this rather be a comment and not an answer. thanks for the link

Comment: I thought comments where for asking for more information or suggesting improvements to provided code...