# Render React elements on different points

Tags: reactjs

How can I render 2 React elements that share their props in two different part of a page?

I need this because I don't want to render every part of the page with react, but some elements that are in the `<Header />` share some props with the `<Footer />`

Example:

```html
<body>
  <HeaderReactElement />
  tons of html code
  <FooterReactElement />
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of how you currently have your `<Header />` and `<Footer />` built? There are ways that would work, but it might prove less convoluted just to duplicate those elements unless they're especially expensive.

Comment: I believe the solution is equivalent to what I posted here, where an editor and display share the same props:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248234/react-js-set-input-value-from-sibling-component/24251931. This post should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your header/footer element, you pass in a props. There's no reason not to reuse the exact same props.

If the data will change, then the props should have a callback function that the header and footer can listen to and force a re-render.

```
  //example to listen to changes
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.callback = (function(){
      this.forceUpdate();
    }).bind(this);
    this.props.on('change',this.callback);
  },
```